# Помогите подправить регулярку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача искать по тексту ссылки и обрамлять их в соответствующие теги. Есть регулярка, которая частично с этим справляется при условии, что после ссылки не идет какого-либо тега. Например текст `Какой-то текст http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ какой-то текст` будет обрабатываться как `Какой-то текст <a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</a> какой-то текст`
А вот строка `<p>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</p>` уже будет обрабатываться как `<p><a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</p>">http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</p></a>`

Вот регулярка c preg_replace:

```
$ret = preg_replace("~(?<!href=\")(?<!src=\")(http|https|ftp|ftps)://(.*?)(\s|\n|[,.?!](\s|\n)|$)~", '<a href="$1://$2">$1://$2</a>$3',$text);
```

Видимо нужно поставить какой-то ограничитель на символ <, но я не в курсе как это сделать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлено (не очень понятно, зачем сделаны такие сложности)

Можно сделать так:

```
$ret = preg_replace(
    '~(?<!href=[\'"])(?<!src=[\'"])((?:http|https|ftp|ftps)://[^,<>"\'\x00-!]+)~', 
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Для более точного построения выражения нужно смотреть более-менее полную выборку текстов, в которых будет работать скрипт.

Comment: В таком случае вообще не отрабатывает (регексп возвращает исходную строку)

Comment: Несколько упростил выражение. Обновил ответ

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=ascii&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=D2DkVqePC4KjsgHTvoPIAw запятая вполне приветствуется в URL

Comment: @ReinRaus Это да. Я поэтому и написал про выборку текстов. Если попытаться парсить по-правильному, можно нечаянно захватывать и куски текста после URL. А после URL иногда ставят запятую или точку (но точку-то явно нельзя как стоп-символ использовать)

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите обрабатывать подобный текст, то надо работать с текстом как с HTML, а не чистым текстом. В HTML обрабатывать исключительно текстовые ноды.
Например так это можно сделать с помощью SimpleDomHTML:

```
include( "simple_html_dom.php" );
$text = <<<HEREDOC
<a href="http://test.ru">test</a>
<img src="http://test2.ru"/>
<p>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</p>
<p><p></p></p>
HEREDOC;
$dom = str_get_html( $text );
$nodes = Array( $dom->root );
$counter = 0;
while( $counter < sizeof( $nodes ) ) {
    for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof( $nodes[$counter]->nodes ); $i++ ) $nodes[] = $nodes[$counter]->nodes[$i];
    $counter++;
};
$textNodes = array_filter( $nodes, function( $item ) { return $item->nodetype == 3; } );
$textNodes = array_merge( $textNodes );
for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof( $textNodes ); $i++ ) {
    $textNodes[$i]->innertext = preg_replace("~((?:https?|ftps?)://\\S++)~", '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $textNodes[$i]->innertext );;
};
echo htmlspecialchars( $dom );
```

Исходный текст:

```
<a href="http://test.ru">test</a>
<img src="http://test2.ru"/>
<p>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</p>
<p><p></p></p>
```

Результат:

```
<a href="http://test.ru">test</a> 
<img src="http://test2.ru"/> 
<p><a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</a></p>
<p><p></p></p>
```